# why get string from redis, will miss blank space

Tags: redis

For example:
I get string by command, there is a blank space \x00
127.0.0.1:6379> `get "87102213_87102208"
"173275,3915125,10,\x00"`

but in code in print log, the blank space is missed.  Did you know why?

`log_error("reply->str:%s,reply->len:%d",reply->str,reply->len);

reply->str:173275,3915125,10,,reply->len:19`

Answer (score 3):

Well \x00 is not a blank space, this is a nul char, which in C also happens to be the string terminator character. Most C API using strings as parameter will consider the string stops at the first \x00 character. This probably includes this log_error function.

However, Redis is binary safe, and all characters are meaningful including the nul char. When this value has been inserted, probably the size was wrong, so the nul char terminating the string was stored as well.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is null. in fact the reply->len include the '\0' but not include null.